# How to restrict input of áÁ éÉ íI óÓ úÚ from spanish keyboard using javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, onkeypress

We have defined this regular expresion [a-zA-Z0-9-] and implemented an onkeypress event to restrict the input, aparently works well, but when using a spanish keyboard it allows to insert the á é í ó ú character, which are generated pressing 2 keys and the implemented solution does not block this input.  Obiously the keypress event should not be used in this cases.  Does any one have an idea of a better approach to implement this restriction?.  The requirement is to avoid the input of characters other than [a-zA-Z0-9-] but character by character

Answer (score 0):

Key event handler regex have to be anchored. Try `^[a-zA-Z0-9-]+$`

Comment: The problem i am facing is:  keypress event is not being triggered when deadacute key is pressed,  you know á é í ó ú are generated pressing deadacute key and then a e i o u.  keypress event does not work in those cases

Comment: I do mostly MFC, but after some reading, I'll take a guess. Every key should have a keydown/keyup event, even dead keys. Try handling those events, look for  `"U+0302" (Combining Circumflex Accent key)` the dead key you speak of. If found do a call to preventDefault() on that element for that key only.

Comment: Also there might be a workaround here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721499/differency-normal-characters-and-half-characters-on-keydown