# Detect entered character with jquery(spanish,áúí)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on @mention feature and need to load list of users that start with entered character in an input text field .
The problem is with Spanish character like (íáúóé).
in my code I use keypress and keydown to detect characters but in Spanish the keypress event doesn't fire .
in order to type the "á" user need to press two keys 
first one is "´" and second is "a" ,then we got "á".

in keydown event using the method String.fromCharCode(e.which || e.keyCode) on this key"´" return "å" 
The question how to catch this scenario?
Thanks

Comment: There's an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721499/differency-normal-characters-and-half-characters-on-keydown)

Comment: already checked it but the event is deprecated

Comment: how about actually analyzing the text input?